# weird behavior on many ajax posts

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

guys!
Here is my issue. I have a select that changes the price range using jquery ajax post. The problem is, once in a while, no particular trigger, the post action fails and I get a 404 error, (after many 200 OKs).Have you encountered anything like this before? Might this be related to the code or is just a server problem?
This is the js function:

```
function changePriceRange(event_id,elem){
alert('pr'+elem.val());
var data  = 
    {
        event_id:event_id,
        prange:elem.val(),
        event_name:$('#event_name').val(),
        event_date:$('#event_date3').val()
    }
if(event_id==0){
    var my_url = base_url+'change_prange_new';
}else{
    var my_url = base_url+'change_prange';
}
var request = 
    {
        url:my_url,
        type:'POST',
        data:data,
        success:function(response)
          {
            $('#section3_items').html(response);
          } 
    }
$.ajax(request);

//update gifts section

var data2  = 
    {
        event_id:event_id,
        prange:elem.val()
    }
var request2 = 
    {
        url:base_url+'update_gifts_section',
        type:'POST',
        data:data2,
        success:function(response)
          {
            $('#gifts_section').html(response);
          } 
    }
$.ajax(request2);
```

}

..and the 404 error is happening on update_gifts_section. Thank you..

Comment: Can you show some server logs with the exact paths that fail?

Comment: first `alert(update_gifts_section);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a server replies with code 404, it means the document corresponding to the URL of the request is not found.

In your ajax call about "Update Gifts", you specify the URL as

```
url:base_url+'update_gifts_section'
```

If base_url is a static variable (means not changing with respect to some piece of code), then the URL is always the same. If a request gets HTTP200 and another request gets HTTP404, it means the problem is based on server, not the code. (Which is basically your question).

To solve the issue, adding more details about how you are calling this method, what url is called (observe with fiddler etc.) would be helpful.

Comment: The same url is called every time. I took a picture of how this error looks like in Firebug, but since this is my first post, not sure I can upload it here. I think too it is related to the server, but not sure why it does this. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: After I moved the project on client's server, the error didn't take place anymore. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out more about the error. A 404 means the page is not found so is there a problem with `base_url`? Is it sometimes null, for instance?

The best thing for you to do is to add a failure callback so that you know when the ajax call fails. This will help you figure out the problem:

```
var request2 =      
{         
   url:base_url+'update_gifts_section',         
   type:'POST',         
   data:data2,         
   success:function(response)           
   {             
      $('#gifts_section').html(response);           
   }     
   error: function(xhr,err){     
      alert('failure');   
      alert("readyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: "+xhr.status);     
      alert("responseText: "+xhr.responseText);        {     
   } 
}
```

Comment: No, the base url is the same every time..That is the problem. I don't know what triggers that. I will try your failure catch to see what happens. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i just update your code to look better...

```
function changePriceRange(event_id,elem){
alert('pr'+elem.val());
var my_url = (!event_id) ? base_url+'change_prange_new' : base_url+'change_prange';
jQuery.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:my_url,        
        data:({
                event_id:event_id,
                prange:elem.val(),
                event_name:jQuery('#event_name').val(),
                event_date:jQuery('#event_date3').val()
              }),
        success:function(response)
          {
            jQuery('#section3_items').html(response);
          },
        error: function(xhr,err){     
          alert('failure');   
          alert("readyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: "+xhr.status);     
          alert("responseText: "+xhr.responseText);  
        }
});

//update gifts section

jQuery.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:base_url+'update_gifts_section',        
        data:({
                 event_id:event_id,
                 prange:elem.val()
             }),
        success:function(response){
            jQuery('#gifts_section').html(response);
        },
        error: function(xhr,err){     
          alert('failure');   
          alert("readyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: "+xhr.status);     
          alert("responseText: "+xhr.responseText);  
        },
        statusCode: {
                404: function() {alert('page not found');}
        }   

});

}
```